# trim object contents in csv import

Tags: powershell

I need to run a trim method on each value extracted from the csv import object. haven't tried something like below but for me I don't want to have to define a trim command at the end of each one of my variables being passed to functions.

```
$csvobj = "c:\somestuff.csv"

foreach ($csvitem in $csvobj) {
$csvitem.value1.trim()
$csvitem.value2.trim()
}
```

Thanks in advance, SS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will trim all values in the csv file and assign the result to $csv.

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\somestuff.csv | Foreach-Object {
   $_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {$_.Value = $_.Value.Trim()}  
}
```

Comment: I @Shay Levy Why do you put the same answer again ? ;o)

Comment: In don't think it's the same. I didn't test your answer but imo you over complicated it.

Comment: thank you both. although both have similar syntax the formatting shorthand methods differ in each.

Comment: This code doesn't appear to work for me in powershell 4.0. It does work if I assign the import to a variable 1st then traverse it like so:     `$csv = Import-Csv   c:\somestuff.csv  

    $csv | Foreach-Object {
   $_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {$_.Value = $_.Value.Trim()} }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$a = import-csv "c:\somestuff.csv"
$a | % {$b=$_;$_.psobject.Properties | % {$c=$_.name ;$b."$c"=($b."$c").trim()}}
```

**First** : I import all the lines into `$a`.

**Second** : In a first loop I read each object (each CSV line), then for each object in a second loop I read each property, then I can trim each var.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification of the above accepted answer.  This strips all leading / tailing spaces from all .csv files in the current folder.  Hope it helps!

```
gci -filter *.csv | foreach {
    echo $_.NAME
    $csv = Import-Csv $_.NAME
    $csv | Foreach-Object {   
        $_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object { $_.Value = $_.Value.Trim() } 
    }
    $csv | Export-Csv $_.NAME -NoTypeInformation 
}
```