# Combining data from 2 csv files and create new one

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 2 csv files.
The first has this column:

```
"www.test.com/"
"www.test2.com/"
"www.test3.com/"
"www.test4.com/"
```

and the second has this column:

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
```

Now i want to create a csv file with this form:

```
"www.test.com/a"
"www.test.com/b"
"www.test.com/c"
"www.test.com/d"
"www.test2.com/a"
"www.test2.com/b"
"www.test2.com/c"
"www.test2.com/d"
"www.test3.com/a"
"www.test3.com/b"
"www.test3.com/c"
"www.test3.com/d"
"www.test4.com/a"
"www.test4.com/b"
"www.test4.com/c"
"www.test4.com/d"
```

I want to create a new csv file compining data from both csv files in this way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

### Using [Join-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)

(Performing a `Join` without `-On` (alias `-Using`) parameter will return a **cross join**, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)

```
PS C:\> $Url | Join $Letter

Letter Url
------ ---
a      www.test.com/
b      www.test.com/
c      www.test.com/
d      www.test.com/
a      www.test2.com/
b      www.test2.com/
c      www.test2.com/
d      www.test2.com/
a      www.test3.com/
b      www.test3.com/
c      www.test3.com/
d      www.test3.com/
a      www.test4.com/
b      www.test4.com/
c      www.test4.com/
d      www.test4.com/
```

*Note:*
`Import-Csv` requires headers in the `.csv` file or defined by the '-Header` Parameter (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528112/1701026)

```
$Url = Import-Csv ".\URL.csv" -Header Url
$Letter  = Import-Csv ".\Letter.csv" -Header Letter
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a VBA macro with nested for loops for this. The following would be the steps with no code, I may mock it up later if I have time.

In a macro on a blank spreadsheet.

- put the contents of the first csv in a defined range "rng1"
- put the contents of the second csv in a defined range "rng2"
- start a counter for the rows in the active sheet at k=1.
- for each value in the first range (test1.com)
- for each value in the second range (a)
- set the value of the k-th row in the active sheet to be rng1.value&rng2.value
- increment k
- end insideloop
- end outsideloop

There's a solution hidden here somewhere. Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you column into your respective csv file are for name ColumnURL and ColumnLetter, try this :

```
$ListURL=import-csv "C:\temp\URL.csv"
$ListLetter=import-csv "C:\temp\Letter.csv"

$ListURL | %{$CurrentURL=$_; $ListLetter | %{ "{0}{1}" -f $CurrentURL.ColumnURL, $_.ColumnLetter}}
```